# what is the right way to define typecast operator template in C++

Tags: c++

[this](http://cpp.sh/7aup) code here is my attempt to define a template to typecast or assignment operator. Problem is, this is not calling typecast function template at line 27 while typecasting the object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
struct FFJSON{
    template <typename T>
    FFJSON& operator=(T const& t){
        cout << "Assigning the object" << endl;
        ts=(void*)&t;
        return *this;
    };
    FFJSON& operator=(const char* s){return *this;};
    FFJSON& operator=(const string& s){return *this;};
    FFJSON& operator=(const int& i){return *this;};
    FFJSON& operator=(const unsigned int& i){return *this;};
    template <typename T>
    operator T(){
        cout << "Returning the object." << endl;
        return *ts;
    }
    void* ts;
};
int main(int argh, char** argv) {
    FFJSON f;
    timespec tt = {3,2};
    f = tt;
    timespec& t=(timespec&)f;
    cout << "sec:"<<t.tv_sec<<endl;
    cout << "usec:"<<t.tv_nsec<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Actual output:**

```
Assigning the object
sec:126885484802960
nsec:4197094
```

**Expected output:**

```
Assigning the object
Returning the object
sec:3
nsec:2
```

The similar scenario is giving typecast operator not defined compile time error in an another program.

Comment: Your assignment operator for T looks absolutly dangerous! Nobody who calls FFJSON a = t; would expect 'a' to save a pointer to 't'. 
In Visual Studio it would be possible to write FFJSON a = 0; which would lead to a dangling pointer a.ts because 0 is a temporary value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timespec& t=(timespec&)f;` cannot use the typecast operator because you are casting to `timespec&` and not to `timespec`.

You have to implement

```
 operator T&(){
        cout << "Returning the object." << endl;
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(ts);
    }
```

to make this work.

Please do not use C-style casts in C++ modules. Use `static_cast<>`, `dynamic_cast<>`, `reinterpret_cast<>` and - if you really have to - `const_cast<>` instead.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the following implementation of the assignment operator copies the source value and should work for temporary objects and the typecast operator checks if the conversion may be valid.

```
class FFJSON
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    inline FFJSON& operator=(T const& t){
        cout << "Assigning the object" << endl;
        assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value );
        data.resize(sizeof(t));
        *reinterpret_cast<T*>(data.data()) = t;
        return *this;
    };

    template <typename T>
    inline operator T(){
        cout << "Returning the object." << endl;
        assert(sizeof(T) <= data.size());
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(data.data());
    }

private:
    std::vector<char> data;
};
```

Comment: I'm unable to link to its shared object.`ffjsonTest.cpp:317: undefined reference to 'FFJSON& FFJSON::operator=<timespec>(timespec const&)'
ffjsonTest.cpp:318: undefined reference to 'FFJSON::operator timespec&<timespec>()'`

Comment: Did you define FFJSON in a header file and include it in ffjsonTest.cpp ? This problem should not occur if you are using a single definition of class FFJSON. If the compiler encounters a call to operator= oder operator T it creates the call and the implementation. 
Try to 'inline' your operators and make sure you only have one declaration of FFJSON within all modules.

Answer (score 3):

`template <typename T> operator T()` is fine, but such `T` can only be deduced to a *non-reference* type so this operator will not be used to convert to the type `timespec&`. Instead, your cast is a `reinterpret_cast`, which never performs a user-defined conversion.

In order to write a conversion operator that can produce an lvalue, you would need to write `template <typename T> operator T&()`.

BTW, you can't dereference a void pointer. If your operator template were ever instantiated, you would get a compilation error because of that.

Comment: Is it a language constraint or the compiler constraint?

Comment: You should not be using C-style casts at all. Use the C++ specific static_cast, const_cast, reinterpret_cast and dynamic_cast and you are fine!
If you use 
`timespec& t=static_cast<timespec&>(f);`
the compiler would tell you that it is not working the way you want it.
`auto t = static_cast<timespec>(f);`
will work

Comment: @neckTwi Everything I've told you here is due to the rules of the language.

Comment: I'm unable to link to its shared object.ffjsonTest.cpp:317: undefined reference to 'FFJSON& FFJSON::operator=<timespec>(timespec const&)' ffjsonTest.cpp:318: undefined reference to 'FFJSON::operator timespec&<timespec>()'